# If if if elseif else not working as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've noticed that if I have multiple if statements above an elseif/else statement that the last if, the else if, and the else seem to make its own logic chunk, and it disregards the first ifs:

http://jsbin.com/runudedaja/edit?js,console

```
var a = '';

for (i=1; i<6; i++) {
  if (i === 1) {
    a = 'first if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  if (i === 2) {
    a = 'second if'
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  if (i === 3) {
    a = 'third if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  else if (i === 4) {
    a = 'else if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  else {
    a = 'else';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
}
```

As you can see, `i===1` and `i===2` hit both their specific `if` statement and the last else statement.  But `i===3`, `else if (i===4)`, and `else` all behave as I expected.

*Console Log*

```
"first if 1"
"else 1"
"second if 2"
"else 2"
"third if 3"
"else if 4"
"else 5"
```

** Desired Output **

```
"first if 1"
"second if 2"
"third if 3"
"else if 4"
"else 5"
```

What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's it meant to do? What's your desired output?

Comment: its because you dont have else if on the first if's

Comment: `if (a) {} if (b) {}` is different compared to `if (e) {} else if (b) {}` Sequential ifs will always be checked regardless the previous if is true or not. If/elseif will only check elseif when the if condition is falsey.

Comment: you can use a switch block instead of i

Comment: you are missing else if (...) for first two conditions

Comment: I just fixed it, y'all are too fast lol

Comment: Actually, if if if elseif else working as expected.

Comment: @MichaelRushton haha yea I guess so.  I guess differently than I expected, and was hoping to get some clarification on why, which the question achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Description

You missed the `else if` statements for `i === 2` and `i === 3`, so this became 3 if statement sections without the `else if` statements added below.

### The three if statement blocks:

***The first checks:***

```
if (i === 1) {
    a = 'first if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
}
```

***The second checks:***

```
if (i === 2) {
    a = 'second if'
    console.log(a + " " + i);
}
```

***The third checks:***

```
if (i === 3) {
    a = 'third if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
}
else if (i === 4) {
    a = 'else if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
}
else {
    a = 'else';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
}
```

This means that when `i` is equal to 1 it would be checked by each if block and would hit the first if block and the else of the third block.

### Your Code with changed `if` to `else if`

```js
var a = '';

for (i=1; i<6; i++) {
  if (i === 1) {
    a = 'first if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  else if (i === 2) {
    a = 'second if'
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  else if (i === 3) {
    a = 'third if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  else if (i === 4) {
    a = 'else if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  else {
    a = 'else';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
}
```

### Your Code changed to a `Switch` statement

```js
var a = '';

for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  switch (i) {
    case 1:
      a = 'first if';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
      break;
    case 2:
      a = 'second if'
      console.log(a + " " + i);
      break;
    case 3:
      a = 'third if';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
      break;
    case 4:
      a = 'else if';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
      break;
    default:
      a = 'else';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a couple of `else` keywords.

This code of yours:

```
if (i === 1) {
    a = 'first if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  if (i === 2) {
    a = 'second if'
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  }
  if (i === 3) {
    ...
```

should be:

```
if (i === 1) {
    a = 'first if';
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  } else // <=== NEW "else"
  if (i === 2) {
    a = 'second if'
    console.log(a + " " + i);
  } else // <=== NEW "else"
  if (i === 3) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three separate checks:

1.

```
if (i === 1) {
  a = 'first if';
  console.log(a + " " + i);
}
```

2.

```
if (i === 2) {
  a = 'second if'
  console.log(a + " " + i);
}
```

3.

```
if (i === 3) {
  a = 'third if';
  console.log(a + " " + i);
}
else if (i === 4) {
  a = 'else if';
  console.log(a + " " + i);
}
else {
  a = 'else';
  console.log(a + " " + i);
}
```

This means that if `i` is `1` or `2` then it satisfies the `else` in the third check.

The simplest solution (although not the cleanest), would be to make the second and third `if` into `else if`. The cleanest solution would be to use `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be a switch in that case:

```
console.log((function(){
 switch(i){
  case 1:
    return "its one";
  break;
  case 2:
    return " its two";
  break;
  default:
    return "its sth else";
  break;
 }})(),i);
```

Instead of this iife and return, you could also simply do a=" its sth else" like in your code. Also, i would put the console.log behind the last if , as its quite repetetive.

Answer (score 0):

Else is useless there, and in last if too, btw you might want to use `switch`

```
if (i === 4) {
  a = 'else if';
  console.log(a + " " + i);
}

a = 'else';
console.log(a + " " + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written 2 `if`-statements and 1 `if`/`else-if`/`else` statement:

1.

```
    if (i === 1) {
      a = 'first if';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
    }
```

2.

```
    if (i === 2) {
      a = 'second if'
      console.log(a + " " + i);
    }
```

3.

```
    if (i === 3) {
      a = 'third if';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
    }
    else if (i === 4) {
      a = 'else if';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
    }
    else {
      a = 'else';
      console.log(a + " " + i);
    }
```

Code execution enters each of these if statements, which means for all your iterations when `i` is not `3` the final `else` clause gets executed.